# Allocation List in Instruments Tool

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, instruments

I am using Instrument Tool for Tracing and improving my Application.
I want to know what does "Allocations List" do in Instruments.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The allocations list shows every memory allocation your app makes. If you open the extended detail view, you can step through each allocation. In most situations examining every memory allocation is unnecessary because iOS apps make so many memory allocations.

Most people will use the statistics and call tree views more than the allocations list. The statistics view lets you see how much memory your app is using. The call tree view lets you find the places in your code that are allocating the most memory. But the allocations list is there when you need to dig deeper into your app's memory allocations.

**UPDATE**

Most of the columns are self-explanatory. The timestamp tells you when the memory allocation occurred, relative to application launch. The Live column tells you if the memory has been freed. If there's a dot in the Live column, the memory has not been freed. The responsible library is the library that allocated the memory. The responsible caller is the function that allocated the memory. The address is the address where the memory was allocated.

The Category column is the toughest to explain. In your screenshot, all the categories are Malloc, which are general memory allocations. Instruments separates these allocations according to the size of the allocation, which is why there are Malloc 3 KB, 4 KB, 5 KB, 6 KB, 7 KB, and 12 KB in your screenshot. Other common categories are Apple's classes, which have the prefixes NS, UI, and CF.

Comment: Thanks.But I want to know each and every functionality, like that, TimeStamp, Live, Size, Responsible Library. What they are doing in Allocations List. Can you Please help on this.